# Change the hover text in ggplotly geom_bar according the count

Tags: r, shiny, geom-bar, ggplotly

So I'm making a web app using R Shiny. I want to show a bar chart with ggplotly here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EdCZ.png). I want to change the hovertext to Category: ... Count: ..

I tried like the code below, but I don't know what to call the value of the count. I've tried to call count, frequency. But it doesn't work. Any idea how to fix this?

```
  output$plotb <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(ggplot(data=dataset(),aes(x=dataset()[[input$bo]],
                                       text=paste("Category: ", dataset()[[input$bo]],
                                                  "<br>Count: ")))+
               geom_bar(fill='cornflowerblue',color="black")+
               labs(title=sprintf("Bar chart of %s",input$bo),
                    x=input$bo,y="Frequency")+
               theme_light(),tooltip="text")
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result would be via `ggplot2::after_stat` which allows you to access the values computed by a stat, e.g. in case of `geom_bar` the default stats layer is `stat="count"`. Unfortunately doing so requires some extra work to get the labels of the categories. To this end I added a reactive `categories()` to my example code, which converts the input variable to a factor and returns the factor's levels. Doing so allows to add the category labels inside `after_stat` via `categories()[x]`:

As you provided no data I made use of `ggplot2::mpg` as example data:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plotb")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  input <- list(bo = "class")
  
  dataset <- reactive({ mpg })
  
  categories <- reactive({ levels(factor(dataset()[[input$bo]])) })
  
  output$plotb <- renderPlotly({
    ggplot(data = dataset(), aes(
      x = .data[[input$bo]],
      text = after_stat(paste(
        "Category: ", categories()[x],
        "<br>Count: ", count
      ))
    )) +
      geom_bar(fill = "cornflowerblue", color = "black") +
      labs(
        title = sprintf("Bar chart of %s", input$bo),
        x = input$bo, y = "Frequency"
      ) +
      theme_light()
    
    ggplotly(tooltip = "text")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]